# Application not same rendering in phone and in ripple

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ripple

New to Apach cordova, trying to make a simple application.
Here's its result viewed into google chrome using Ripple (for phonegab/cordova emulation)

[image: IntroductionInNavigator]

and here's the result when i click on the button

[image: ProfileInformationInNavigator]

it seems to appear perfectly and now when i try to create a project for android with cordova and then compile it using android studio i get this result:

[image: IntroductionInPhone]

and here's the problem

[image: ProfileInformationInPhone]

If my code is needed to check where the problem is, tell me i'll upload it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem is probably the viewport meta tag, post it if you have one, and if you don't have one, then that might be the problem

Comment: Exactly !  thanks for the answer , problems solved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, meta missing for viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

thanks to jcesarmobile.